# Trying to divide a given amount of money into different bills

Tags: c++, c

So basically, I want to write a program that takes any given amount of money (for example 93) and divides that number into different money bills that shows me how I can pay. In this case, 93 is supposed to become

4 $20 bills
1 $10 bill
3 $1 bills

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int money;

    printf(" In this program you will be able to put in any certain amount of money and we will divide it into $20 bills, $10 bills, $5 bills and $1 bills. \n");
    printf(" How much money do you have?:");
    scanf("%d", &money);

    int twentyb = money/20;
    int tenb = (money - (twentyb*20))/10 ;
    int fiveb = (money - (tenb*10-twentyb*20))/5;
        int oneb = (money - (tenb*10-twentyb*20-fiveb*65))/1;

    printf("\n The given amount can be divided into:");
    printf("\n $20 bills:%d", twentyb);
    printf("\n $10 bills:%d", tenb);
    printf("\n $5  bills:%d ", fiveb);
    printf("\n $1  bills:%d \n", oneb);
    return 0;

}
```

What I get after typing in 93 dollars is

```
$20 bills: 4
$10 bills: 1
$5  bills: 16
$1  bills: 90
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You need to add the terms together in `(tenb*10-twentyb*20)` and `(tenb*10-twentyb*20-fiveb*65)` instead of subtracting.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different languages.  For example, C++ has scope resolution and inheritance, C doesn't.  In C, I can have a variable called `class`.  Or are you programming in both, for example using a source file written in C in a C++ project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arithmetic is wrong. You're mixing up `+` and `-`. Also, that `65` should be a `5`, but I guess that's just a typo.

```
int twentyb = money / 20;
int tenb = (money - (twentyb * 20)) / 10;
int fiveb = (money - (tenb * 10 + twentyb * 20)) / 5;
int oneb = (money - (tenb * 10 + twentyb * 20 + fiveb * 5)) / 1;
```

Comment: Thanks m8, seems like i gotta go refresh my maths.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to solve your problem. After dividing by `20`, `10` or `5`, you can take the remainder each time as money.

And for the last time you don't have to divide by `1`, as it's going to be same as the dividend.

```cpp
int twentyb = money/20;
money = money%20;
int tenb = money/10;
money = money%10;
int fiveb = money/5;
money = money%5;
int oneb = money;
```